# How to use Caliburn.Micro in a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) project

Tags: plugins, add-in, caliburn.micro, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In my Visual Studio Extension(VSIX), I want to implement a WPF - MVVM component. In this scope, I want to use Caliburn Micro to help me with the bindings and project structure. I don't know how to include the `Bootstrapper` class and how this class should look like.

So my question is: It is possible to use Caliburn Micro in a Visual Studio Extension(VSIX) project?

Comment: A duplicate of [this one](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/333)?

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of this issue. This is for creating a VSIX - Caliburn.Micro for using it in WPF based apps: [Caliburn.Micro VS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anuviswan.CaliburnMicroTemplatePack). What I want is to have a VSIX based app in which to take advantage of Caliburn.Micro automation.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Maybe you should get support from the team who supports Caliburn.Micro.